# How to compare two range values for equality?

Tags: excel, vba

Following is my code

```
Data = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B3:E6").Value
targetValue = ActiveSheet.Range(targetcellL, targetcellR).Value

If Data = targetValue Then
     MsgBox "Match Found"

End If
```

The if condition give me error of "Runtime error 13 Type Mismatch"
How can i compare two range value?

Answer (score 2):

you have to check every item

as follows (you may want to add some check to ensure arrays sizes are the same):

```
Data = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B3:E6").Value
targetValue = ActiveSheet.Range(targetcellL, targetcellR).Value

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim match As Boolean
match = True
For i = LBound(Data,1) to UBound(Data,1)
    For j = LBound(Data,2) to UBound(Data,2)    
        If Data(i, j) <> targetValue(i, j) Then
            match = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    if Not match Then Exit For
Next
If match Then MsgBox "Match Found"
```

---

as for the *"short way"* you seem to be after, you may consider using a helper `Function()`:

```
Data = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("B3:E6").Value
targetValue = ActiveSheet.Range(targetcellL, targetcellR).Value

If DoArraysMatch(Data, targetValue) Then MsgBox "Match Found"
```

and here's the heleper `DoArraysMatch()` function:

```
Function DoArraysMatch(arr1 As variant, arr2 As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim match As Boolean

    match = True
    For i = LBound(arr1,1) to UBound(arr1,1)
        For j = LBound(arr1,2) to UBound(arr1,2)    
            If arr1(i, j) <> arr2(i, j) Then
                match = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        if Not match Then Exit For
    Next
    DoArraysMatch = match
End Function
```

Comment: As there any short way to do it as i know that Data.value and target.value has the same range.

Comment: You should qualify what _short_ is to mean for you. If it's all about _short time_ then provided code is quite fast. If you're after some  _short code_ not to plumber your "main" code, then see edited answer for the use of the `DoArraysMatch()` helper function you can keep "out of sight"

Answer (score 0):

```
Function ArraysEqual() As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    ArraysEqual = True
    For Each cell In rng1
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, cell.Value) = 0 Then
            ArraysEqual = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```